# Thin border renders unevenly in LWC (Resolved)

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, css, lightning-design-system, slds

I'm curious why does lightning renders the thin border of table cells uneven while in code the border-top and border-bottom was set to 1px dotted grey

I hope someone can help. Thanks

[image]

Comment: can you share html too?

Comment: hi @MukulMahawariya, I have resolve the issue already. I think there is a bug in rendering non-slds styling. But it was resolved when I enclose the whole row with border. It works fine now. Thanks